# Just upgraded to the latest kernel version and the desktop stops responding

Tags: upgrade, kernel, updates, .desktop

I have just completed my system update(it downloaded about 300 MB), after a restart the desktop stopped responding, there is no wallpaper on the desktop, right click does not work(it is happening only on the desktop, everywhere else it's just fine). What I think is I have just now upgraded to the latest kernel version(3.13.0-24-generic
) so maybe the new kernel is causing the problems.I use an nvidia graphic card with drivers, the output of the  command

> glxinfo | grep OpenGL

gave the following output

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 310M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 304.117
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 304.117
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

I hope its not the graphic card problem because I am using KDE Now on my laptop without any issues , so only unity is affected.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What are you doing exactly or what program do you run when the desktop suddenly stops working ??

Comment: After I enter my password in the login screen, the same back drop(with the writing "Ubuntu 14.04" Remains, on the desktop right click does not work, Wallpaper will not load, everything except desktop(like unity  launcher, applications) work normally.How do I solve this? it is getting very irritating.

Comment: We can check to see if the problem has something to do with Unity by pressing CTRL + ALF + F1 at login screen, entering details and at prompt type:  sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop    ...this gives you an alternative desktop to select from the login screen to test...

Comment: This reads as a bug and perhaps should be a bug report on launchpad.  If you think its a kernel issue - boot from an older kernel (press shift on boot and choose old-versions from grub)

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue similar to this and I fixed it by connecting to the internet and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and typing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

Comment: When I type "sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging" the reply is "Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: unity-team staging
". I tried reinstalling Ubuntu desktop and unity but it is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: If [darexon's](https://askubuntu.com/users/296547/darexon) suggestion doesn't help, you might have something to try here:
if `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` lists kernels in the 3.13.0 'series' with versions ending in -27, -29 or -30...

then I suggest that you make sure to reinstall the last that actually works (for me!) - i.e. the one that has version ending in -24
See [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/489181/289138) for help on how to do it, the commands there installs linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic, then purge -30 and follows that with the two commands that should make the -24 bootable.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+ALT+F1
1st 
`$ sudo apt-get autoremove-ubuntu desktop && sudo apt-get autoremove unity && sudo apt-get autoremove ibglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev`

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-2d && sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev && sudo apt-get install unity
 && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo reboot
```

after the reboot's done CTRL+ALT+F1 again & reset your unity "`$ setsid unity`" 
then login & install your Graphic card drivers